# Error upon starting a nested Virtual machine inside a windows server 2012 vm

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, hypervisor

I have created a VM with Windows Server 2012 using a VMWare workstation with Windows 11 on a Ryzen laptop with virtualization enabled in the BIOS. Upon creating another virtual machine using Hyper-V on a Windows Server 2012 virtual machine and starting it, I get the error

```
Could not start virtual machine because hypervisor is not running
```

On the physical PC when I use the `systeminfo` command in command prompt, in the hypervisor requirements it says

```
A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for hyper-v will not be displayed".
```

[image: Error - Virtual Machine could not start because the hypervisor is not running]

Answer (score 0):

Run the following in power shell (as administrator):

1. `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V`
2. `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto`
3. Restart and start the VM

Optionally run the following:

1.a. `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart`

1.b. `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt reply, do I run the power shell commands in the windows server VM or the Physical PC with windows 11?

Comment: Hi you are welcome on the Physical PC

Comment: I tried the powershell commands, but it did not resolve the issue. I would like to point out that in the windows features list on my physical PC with windows eleven Hyper-v is not displayed...could that be the cause of not being able to start the nested virtual machine?

Comment: just curious and not bc i prefer one of each other have you tried Oracle VirtualBox ? Give it a try, at least if it runs a VM with the HyperV  enable (displayed as a dropdown under virtualization) on Virtual Box we do not have any doubt.

Comment: actually, it's an assignment so I'll have to do it in VMware only, can you think of any other fix...I'm still stuck on this problem